# Can someone explain batch-size and timestep for a regression model using RNN?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, regression, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on a regression model, which has 50 datapoints per hour. I am having a hard time deciding on the difference between batch size and time-step. From my understanding, batch size is used to decide how many datapoints do we want to consider before making a prediction. The larger the value, the longer it takes for the model to converge. If that is the case I am clear on definition of batch size. So if my model isn't taking very long, can I just use the maximum? Would that maximum be the test datasize?

How about timesteps then? For a model where you measure let's say temperature every minute till 30 hours, what would the timestep be?
I would appreciate it if someone who knows about regression using RNN could answer my doubts.

Comment: Have a look to [EpyNN](https://epynn.net)

Comment: If you are suggesting I look into EpyNN. I did search for the answer to my question there, I could not find anything, unfortunately. Thanks though.

Comment: Read the source code. Timestep is related to RNN forward propagation. Batch size is related to data embedding. Just do a ctrl+F for "step" on the RNN page, alternatively. Moreover you may find answer on the data preparation side (like your question about temperature) there [link](https://epynn.net/nnlive/dummy_time/prepare_dataset.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given :

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[[1], [0], [1]]])

print(x.shape)
```

Output:

```
(1, 3, 1)
```

This is for `m` samples `s` timesteps with `e` measurements per timesteps.

```
(m, s, e)
```

In any case the number of data points is the size of the array so:

```
m * s * e
```

The number of data point per sample:

```
s * e
```

If you meaure temperature every second for an hour on one sample.

```
(1, 3600, 1)
```

If you measure let say temperature and humidity.

```
(1, 3600, 2)
```

Let say you do that simultaneously for 2 samples (in place A and B).

```
(2, 3600, 2)
```

Batch size is just not related at all.

For each epoch it just means how many samples you want to run at once. For 100 samples batch size 50 you have two weight update per epoch for instance.

Comment: I am confused by what you mean when you say on one sample. My x data has the same shape [instances, timesteps, # of independent variables], so if I have 2500 datapoints, the shape becomes [2500, timesteps, 8], 8 here is the number of input features. 

Thank you for your time and explanation, it means a lot.

Comment: sample means instance in your nomenclature. But definitely let's browse EpyNN website and source code (see github) in details. I wrote EpyNN for this :).

Comment: "Input X of shape (m, s, e) with m equal to the number of samples, s the number of steps in sequence and e the number of elements within each step of the sequence."

I did go through the github source code, but how to select the number of steps is still unclear to me. Let's say we measure over 20 hours and get 2000 datapoints. 2000 is the m. If you want to change s, wouldn't you have to change m as well. If m is 2000, s has to be 1?

Comment: Also, thanks for the batch size explanation. It is the opposite of what I said earlier. The smaller the batch size the more the weights are updated per epoch and the longer it takes.

Comment: You do not "select" the number of timesteps. I think you are confused and you think that the number of RNN cells/units is related to the timesteps. It is not in any way. See [here](https://epynn.net/nnlive/author_music/train.html#RNN(sequences=True)-Flatten-(Dense)n-with-Dropout). For batch size it is not necessarily linked (only) with speed. See [here](https://epynn.net/nnlive/dummy_time/train.html#RNN-Dense-with-SGD).

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/predictive-analysis-rnn-lstm-and-gru-to-predict-water-consumption-e6bb3c2b4b02

This is an example similar to what I am working on. Here the author uses 30 as their timestep as they want to check for a monthly trend. In my case, I have 30-hour data (50 points per hour). So would 50 be my timestep?

As for the batch size, I think I understand. Updating weights too often per epoch can be a problem and you have to test and see which batch size works best for your dataset?

Comment: If you measure the temperature in your house every day for a month then m = 1 (your house) s = 30 (days in month) e = 1 (univariate, you measure one thing for each step). For batch size yes you have to test and see. In general you don t know what is going to work with nnet. So you need to try and see.

Comment: I see, thanks. If you have the time, please do visit the towardsdatascience article and let me know if the author has an incorrect method posted there. I am new to deep learning and I rely on such articles and helpful users like you to learn.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, these posts will be helpful in a first place, then they will impair your progress. You can't talk about the thing in a single post. So earlier or later you ll face inconsistencies between posts, you ll realize some were just wrong, etc, etc. Btw think about accepting my answer if that was helpful!

Comment: Yes, I did ask someone with good background in RNN and now have a theoretical understanding of what is going on. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.